# Mega dropdown menu css for mysql database data

Tags: php, jquery, css, mysql, megamenu

I want to make mega dropdown menu that comes from mysql database. Below is my php code. The code is working well. But the problem is I am unable to make mega dropdown menu for the code below.

I need the mega menu like the example here : https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/bootstrap-mega-menu

My problem is how will I make more `div` with the below php code .

Plz help me the `css` for the mega drop down menu as shown above.

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT id, product, parent_id, category_link FROM category ORDER BY parent_id, id";
$results = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error()) ;
if($results)
{
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
    {
        $category['categories'][$result['id']] = $result; 
        $category['parent_cats'][$result['parent_id']][] = $result['id']; 
    }
}

function getCategories($parent, $category) 
{
    $html = "";
    if (isset($category['parent_cats'][$parent]))
    {
        $html .= "<div id='wrapper'>";
        $html .= "<ul class='mega-menu'>\n";
        foreach ($category['parent_cats'][$parent] as $cat_id)
        {
            if (!isset($category['parent_cats'][$cat_id]))
            {
              $html .= "<li class='mega-menu-drop'>\n  <a class='mega-menu-content' href='" . $category['categories'][$cat_id]['category_link'] . "'>" . $category['categories'][$cat_id]['product'] . "</a>\n</li> \n";
            }
            if (isset($category['parent_cats'][$cat_id]))
            {
              $html .= "<li class='mega-menu-drop'>\n  <a class='mega-menu-content' href='" . $category['categories'][$cat_id]['category_link'] . "'>" . $category['categories'][$cat_id]['product'] . "</a> \n";
              $html .= getCategories($cat_id, $category);
              $html .= "</li> \n";
            }
        }
        $html .= "</ul> \n";
        $html .= "</div>";

    }
    return $html;
}
?>
<?php echo $data['category'] = getCategories(0, $category);?>
```

Comment: can you ask a question? 
you already have that example you could follow. apply proper class names and refine your markup which is created by your PHP code.

Comment: I am  unable to create mega menu for css as in the example page.

Answer (score 0):

as of your comment. i guess you need some CSS. 
this will work on mouse hover. but not on click like in your example:

```
.mega-menu-drop {
  display:none
}

.mega-menu:hover .mega-menu-drop {
  display:block
}
```

Comment: pls provide a rendered markup example. I can't work with the PHP code as I don't know your data